# Authorization in pylons

Tags: python, pylons

I use pylons for develop of my project. What lib I can use to authorization users? I know about authkit, but he not supported now.

Answer (score 2):

Not related to Pylons specifically, I usually use repoze.who for authentication and repoze.what for authorization.

http://docs.repoze.org/who

http://docs.repoze.org/what

Comment: Can you give some example for I can use it? Because I see it early but can't understood how use it.

Comment: Basically the idea is to wrap your app in a repoze.what middleware with `setup_what`. this repoze.what middleware requires a repoze.who stuffs such as authenticators, challengers. When you need authorization check, you call `is_met` on a repoze.what predicate. There are many built-in repoze.what predicates and you can write them yourself too. I have some sample gluing code at https://bitbucket.org/vithon/vithon-forum/src/abab8f2a7aef/viforum/forum.py. It uses repoze.who.plugins.openid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent tutorial on how to use repoze.who/repoze.what. Which in my opinion is the best way to go. [repoze.who/what tutorial](http://cd34.com/blog/framework/repoze-whorepoze-what-with-pylons-step-by-step/)